# Nokogiri parsing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, parsing, nokogiri

I have some XML:

```
xml = <<-EOT
<xml>
    <advcampaign_categories>
        <category id="85">Sport</category>
        <category id="79">Mobile</category>
        <category id="62">Flowers</category>
    </advcampaign_categories>
</xml>
EOT
```

and want parse it:

```
id=[]
text=[]
doc = Nokogiri::XML(xml)
doc.search('advcampaign_categories').each do |cat|
  c = cat.at('category')
  text << c.text
  id << c['id']    
end
h = Hash[text.zip id]
```

My goal is get a hash like `{sport:85, mobile:79..etc}`.

The problem with this code is it only returns ONE element `sport:85`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: there only is one `advcampaign_categories`, that's why you're only getting one result. Change it to `doc.search('category).each` instead

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
require 'nokogiri'

doc = Nokogiri::XML.parse <<-EOT
<xml>
    <advcampaign_categories>
        <category id="85">Sport</category>
        <category id="79">Mobile</category>
        <category id="62">Flowers</category>
    </advcampaign_categories>
</xml>
EOT

# if you are >= 2.1
doc.css('category').map { |node| [node.text, node['id'].to_i] }.to_h
# => {"Sport"=>85, "Mobile"=>79, "Flowers"=>62}
# if you are below version < 2.1
Hash[doc.css('category').map { |node| [node.text, node['id'].to_i] }]
# => {"Sport"=>85, "Mobile"=>79, "Flowers"=>62}
```